# Java shallow copy array

Tags: java, arrays

if this is a shallow copy

```
double[] a = new double[100];
a = b; // let b be some other double array[100]
```

I understand that the better way to do this is using a for loop or using

```
System.arrayCopy(b,0,a,0,100);
```

However what happens to this?

```
public double[] function1(){
    returns somedouble[100];
}

double[] a = new double[100];
a = function1(); // i believe this will also be a shallow copy

System.arrayCopy(function1(),0,a,0,100); // will this call function1 100 times?
```

Comment: a = b is not a shallow copy. Its just changing the a pointer to point to the start of b.

Comment: If it's primitive array, then there's no difference between shallow and deep copy. First, you need to understand primitive/reference type in Java. Then you learn primitive/reference arrays. Then you know there's "shallow or deep copy" about reference array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
double[] a = new double[100];
a = b; // let b be some other double array[100]
```

Create an array named `a` of double with size of 100. Now when you `a = b` will copy the reference of b array to variable a.

```
     +--------------------------------------------+  <- Suppose whole
a->  | 2.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  array is filled 
     +--------------------------------------------+  with value 2.5

     +--------------------------------------------+  <- Suppose whole
b->  | 7.9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  array is filled 
     +--------------------------------------------+  with value 7.9
```

after a = b

```
     +--------------------------------------------+  <- Suppose whole
     | 2.5 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  array is filled 
     +--------------------------------------------+  with value 2.5

a->  +--------------------------------------------+  <- Suppose whole
b->  | 7.9 |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  array is filled 
     +--------------------------------------------+  with value 7.9
```

So now a and b pointing to same array.

```
public double[] function1(){
    return somedouble[100];
}

double[] a = new double[100];
a = function1();
```

Now same thing is happening here. You create an array named a and then call `function1()` and again assigned the returning array reference to a.

```
System.arraycopy(function1(), 0, a, 0, 100);
```

Here the calling order will be

1 -> function1() will be called and the returning array reference will be saved in a temporary variable.

2 -> call to `System.arraycopy(temporary variable, 0, a, 0, 100)`

So `function1()` will be called only once.

As a side note make sure you use `System.arraycopy(args)` instead of `System.arrayCopy(args)`

Answer (score 0):

```
    double[] a = new double[100];
    a = b; // let b be some other double array[100]
```

First, It's assigning, not copying.

---

```
    double[] a = new double[100];
    a = function1(); // i believe this will also be a shallow copy
```

It's assigning. you assign the returned value *somedouble[100]* to *a*

---

> System.arrayCopy(function1(),0,a,0,100); // will this call function1 100 times?

No, it won't call function1 100 times. The above code mostly equals to

```
    double[] tmpref = function1();
    System.arrayCopy(tmparr,0,a,0,100);
```

Because it first evaluates the arguments, then it calls *arrayCopy*

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I am not sure who downvoted it, but your answer was definitely helpful to me. Upvote to you sir.